# Select numbers smaller than 10000 using regex in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a very long list that following is a part of it:

```
English

4,000,000

AfricanAmerican

1,771,000

Irish

1,100,000

Dutch

800,000

German

700,000

Scotch-Irish

0-640,000

NativeAmerican

=0=500,000

Scottish

450,000

Russian

15,000

Austrian

5000

Finnish4000

Swiss

+4000

1820
```

**Now I want to select all comma separated numbers and numbers smaller than 10000 using regex in notepad++**

Following regex is good for comma separated numbers but it can't select numbers smaller than 10000:

```
\d{1,3},\d{3}
```

how to modify it to select numbers smaller than 10000 too?

note that regex must select numbers that combined with words too, like `Finnish4000`

Comment: Are you sure those are comma *separated* numbers, and not "comma as digit grouping"? There always seem to be 3 digits after the comma

Comment: @HansKeﬆing IDK, only greater than 10000 numbers have comma

Comment: Cannot test now, but something like `\d{1,4}|(\d{1,3},\d{3})`?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing your regex is good but have 2 problem - it not select comma and it select unusual numbers like 0 in =0=500,000

Comment: You can turn it around `(?<!\d)(?:\d{1,3},\d{3}|\d{1,4})(?!\d)` https://regex101.com/r/ukWsdi/1 Why should it not match `0` in `=0=` ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird tnq your regex is good but it still not select some comma numbers completely too, I edited my post and some new info to that list, check it again.

Comment: If you don't want to match only zeroes `(?<!\d)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?!0+(?!\d))\d{1,4})(?!\d)` https://regex101.com/r/ENSqhw/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird this list extracted by OCR and some values are incorrect like -0516,062

Comment: @PubgMobile Then you could rule out values that start with a zero `(?<!\d)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?!0)\d{1,4})(?!\d)` https://regex101.com/r/Vy6q1m/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use an alternation, and rule out 1-4 digits numbers that start with a zero.

To prevent partial matches, you can assert no digits to the left and the right.

```
(?<!\d)(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|(?!0)\d{1,4})(?!\d)
```

The regex matches:

- `(?<!\d)` Assert not a digit to the left
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
  - `(?:,\d{3})+` Repeat 1+ times `,` and 3 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `(?!0)\d{1,4}` Negative lookahead, assert not a zero to the right and match 1-4 digits
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(?!\d)` Assert not a digit to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vy6q1m/1)

Comment: this is very good - but have a problem - it can't select correct number of 0816,884 - I mean 816,884

Comment: @PubgMobile It depends on what you want to allow or not, see https://regex101.com/r/Y2B2AL/1